# Vaadin 7 - Bean Validation

Tags: exception, jpa, vaadin, classnotfoundexception, bean-validation

I have been trying out Vaadin 7. Firstly, I must admin that I am quiet a noob at Vaadin and not much familiar with JAVA persistance. I am thus trying to learn bean validation and how to use it. I have followed couple of tutorials, but its really hard to decide which is the latest and correct one for Vaadin 7. Nonetheless, I tried downloading and using the JPA container and the BeanValidator and I can't get it working. Here is the code I am using:

```
package com.example.firstvaadin;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;

public class RegisterBean implements Serializable{

    public  RegisterBean(String email){
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Size(min = 5, max = 50)
    private String email;

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
}
```

and

```
RegisterBean rbean = new RegisterBean("");
BeanItem<RegisterBean> item = new BeanItem<RegisterBean>(rbean);
TextField email = new TextField("email",item.getItemProperty("email"));
email.setImmediate(true);
layout.addComponent(email);
email.setNullRepresentation("");
```

but I hit run-time exceptions on the following Code:
    email.addValidator(new BeanValidator(RegisterBean.class, "email"));

```
The exception is:
    aused by: com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod$MethodException: Invocation of method buttonClick in com.example.firstvaadin.LoginView$1 failed.
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:528)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:167)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:984)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:367)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:56)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/MessageInterpolator$Context
    at com.example.firstvaadin.RegisterView.<init>(RegisterView.java:55)
    at com.example.firstvaadin.LoginView$1.buttonClick(LoginView.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.MessageInterpolator$Context
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
    ... 39 more
```

I have no idea which classes are missing and I have added hibernate jars and validation-api.jar

Can someone please give me a hand?

Also, here is a list of jar files that are in the /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib directory and added as classpath in Eclipse.

```
classmate-0.8.0.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-search-engine-4.3.0.Alpha1.jar
hibernate-search-orm-4.3.0.Alpha1.jar
hibernate-validator-5.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-annotation-processor-5.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-cdi-5.0.0.Final.jar
javax.el-2.2.4.jar
javax.el-api-2.2.4.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.1.GA.jar
joda-time-2.1.jar
jsoup-1.7.1.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar
vaadin-sqlcontainer-1.1.0.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
```

The classnotfound exception is gone but have a new one now:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.validation.spi.ConfigurationState.getParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl.(ValidatorFactoryImpl.java:113)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.buildValidatorFactory(HibernateValidator.java:45)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:217)
>     at
>   javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:111)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.data.validator.BeanValidator.getJavaxBeanValidatorFactory(BeanValidator.java:167)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.data.validator.BeanValidator.getJavaxBeanValidator(BeanValidator.java:182)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.data.validator.BeanValidator.validate(BeanValidator.java:115)
>     at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.validate(AbstractField.java:935)     at
>   com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.validate(AbstractField.java:900)  at
>   com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.getErrorMessage(AbstractField.java:1009)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.beforeClientResponse(AbstractComponent.java:650)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.beforeClientResponse(AbstractField.java:1643)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.ui.AbstractTextField.beforeClientResponse(AbstractTextField.java:100)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.writeUidlResponse(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:799)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.paintAfterVariableChanges(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:728)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleUidlRequest(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:599)
>     at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:315)
>     at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:201)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need hibernate-validator-annotation-processor-5.0.0.Final.jar as a runtime dependency. This is a development library helping to avoid wrong placements of constraints during development.

Regarding validation-api, removing *validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar* works, because you are adding two different version of the same library. *validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar* is the API version for Bean Validation 1.0. This is compatible with Hibernate Validator 4.3.

*validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar* is the Bean Validation 1.1 API which aligns with Hibernate Validator 5.x. Since you use the latter you need the Bean Validation 1.1 API. As simple as that.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure you've already resolved your issue, but for others coming to this late (as I am) and also using Vaadin 7 Framework, the Vaadin Bean Validator is not compatible with Vaadin 7, only Vaadin 6 as mentioned on their download page here:

https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/vaadin-bean-validation

Even in their own demo (jpacontainer-addressbook-demo) they use the hibernate-validator in the pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Hope this helps out others as it has me.

Comment: Vaadin 7 does not need an add-on for that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put some more dependencies in your project. I solved with this ones:

```
    <!--- Dependencies for validating Beans in Vaadin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

With this its more than enought! You may specify the messages putting the `message` field in the `javax.validation.constraints` notation or putting internationalized ones in project properties, looking at the `message` default value like `javax.validation.constraints.Size.message`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add the validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar to WEB-INF/lib

I don't know if there are any any other dependencies.

Comment: Its already in the folder. I don't know what the problem could be?

Comment: The class not found error is gone. It was as problem with adding the jars to the classpath. Now there is a new error which is addedd to the question.

Comment: It appears that removing the `validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar` and leaving the `validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar` solves the problem. Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Well, going by the name of the jars - validation-api-1.1.0-Final supercedes validation-api-1.0.0.GA; you should use either one or the other, but not both.