# Weblogic 12 hibernate validation exception

Tags: java, hibernate, weblogic

I'm getting this exception after switching from Weblogic 11c to Weblogic 12c:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: JpaPersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
...
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.spi.ConfigurationState.getParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl.<init>(ValidatorFactoryImpl.java:113)
at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.buildValidatorFactory(HibernateValidator.java:45)
```

I've found other questions about the topics, but all solutions were about the wrong libraries([Vaadin 7 - Bean Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163162/vaadin-7-bean-validation)). I think my hibernate-validator matches the bean validator library. This is what I have in WEB-INF/lib:

```
hibernate-c3p0-4.2.4.Final.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.2.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.2.4.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.4.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-5.0.1.Final.jar
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
```

Can it be caused by some other dependency?

**EDIT**
I currently have this in my weblogic-application.xml and everything is working:

```
<weblogic-application>

    <prefer-application-packages>
      <package-name>javax.wsdl.*</package-name>
      <package-name>javax.faces.*</package-name>
      <package-name>org.apache.taglibs.*</package-name>
      <package-name>org.springframework.*</package-name>
      <package-name>javax.persistence.*</package-name>
      <package-name>org.hibernate.*</package-name>
      <package-name>javax.validation.*</package-name>
      <package-name>javax.validation.bootstrap.*</package-name>
      <package-name>javax.validation.constraints.*</package-name>
      <package-name>javax.validation.groups.*</package-name>
      <package-name>javax.validation.metadata.*</package-name>
      <package-name>javax.validation.spi.*</package-name>
      <package-name>org.slf4j.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>

    <prefer-application-resources>
      <resource-name>javax.faces.*</resource-name>
      <resource-name>org.apache.taglibs.*</resource-name>
      <resource-name>org.springframework.*</resource-name>
      <resource-name>javax.persistence.*</resource-name>
      <resource-name>javax.validation.*</resource-name>
      <resource-name>org.hibernate.*</resource-name>
    </prefer-application-resources>

</weblogic-application>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` is mainly caused by an invalid library version in your classpath. It seems the WebLogic 12c is using a different version of validation api from what your application expect. In order to force it to use the one in your `WEB-INF/lib` folder you have to specify it using `prefer-web-inf-classes` element in your `weblogic.xml`.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/programming/classloading.html#1082452) is more documentation about `prefer-web-inf-classes`

Comment: I've added the ```javax.validation``` to the ```prefer-web-inf-classes``` and now it works