# How to solve NoSuchMethodError for javax.validation when deploying a spring boot application in weblogic server?

Tags: spring-boot, bean-validation, weblogic12c, hibernate-validator

I am trying to deploy a simple spring boot application that will expose some rest api and I use hibernate entity manager to manipulate entity objects. When I try to deploy this application to Oracle Weblogic 12c, I get the following exception:

```
<Jan 11, 2016 6:20:14 PM BDT> <Error> <Console> <BEA-240003> <Administration Console encountered the following error: weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.spi.ConfigurationState.getParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:73)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:587)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.spi.ConfigurationState.getParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl.<init>(ValidatorFactoryImpl.java:142)
at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.buildValidatorFactory(HibernateValidator.java:35)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at weblogic.validation.validator.ValidationProvider.invoke(ValidationProvider.java:75)
at weblogic.validation.validator.ValidationProvider.buildValidatorFactory(ValidationProvider.java:66)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:302)
.... rest of the stack trace has been omitted ....
```

In short, I am getting

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.validation.spi.ConfigurationState.getParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;

I have gone through similar questions about this problem in stack overflow (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656146/trouble-starting-hibernate-validator-due-to-bean-validation-api), and, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266297/hibernate-error-activating-bean-validation-integration)), but could not fix the problem. I tried tweaking dependencies on hibernate-validator and javax validation api, but it did not help much. Here is some relevant part of my pom file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

And my WEB-INF/weblogic.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90
              http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
        <show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</show-archived-real-path-enabled>
    </container-descriptor>

</weblogic-web-app>
```

The only validation annotation I have used so far is @NotNull (javax.validation.constraints.NotNull). WebLogic Server Version: 12.1.3.0.0 running on Java7.

PS: The project runs fine in Tomcat 8.

Comment: I recommend you clean install your project via maven again and also make sure you enabled annotations if you are using Spring.

Comment: @Omoro, I tried mvn clean package. Same error. What do you mean by enabling annotations?

Comment: You have to configure your Spring project to use annotations by for example adding that to your application context xml file the following `<context:annotation-config />`...that is if you are using annotations. Further check if you have all the necessary dependencies, that exception indicates that you are missing some dependency and check into the depedency if the method your application is using does exist.

Comment: @Omoro, I am using spring boot. These configurations are built in with it. The project runs fine in Tomcat, just can't get it running in Weblogic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve the problem. I wasn't aware of the fact that if prefer-web-inf-classes is disabled from Weblogic admin console, then weblogic ignores the directive specified in weblogic.xml file.

[From Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP602):

> The prefer-web-inf-classes element, if set to true, will cause classes located in the WEB-INF directory of a Web application to be loaded in preference to classes loaded in the application or system classloader. The default value is false. A value specified in the Administration Console will take precedence over a value set manually.

So, instead, I had to specify prefer-application-packages in weblogic.xml file. Here is the updated content of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd
    http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
    http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

<wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>org.springframework.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.hibernate.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.validation.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.validation.spi.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.slf4j.*</package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    <wls:show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</wls:show-archived-real-path-enabled>
</wls:container-descriptor>

</weblogic-web-app>
```

[This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19050054/weblogic-12-hibernate-validation-exception) was quite helpful.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that Weblogic is using Bean Validation 1.0 which aligns with Hibernate Validator 4.x. I am not sure how to get Weblogic to use Bean Validation as bundled in your app (maybe that's what you try to do with `prefer-web-inf-classes`) or how to upgrade the whole app server  to Bean Validation 1.1. Unless you are using method validation, you could try to use the latest 4.x release (4.3.2.Final). You would then remove the `validation-api` dependency from the pom (will be pulled in transitively anyways) or you set it to `1.0.0.GA`.

Comment: you are correct about wls using older version of bean validation. I was aware of that too. So I tried with 4.3.2 and that did not work either. With prefer-web-inf-classes, I can tell wls to use my libs, instead of bundled ones. Updating wls is not an option for me.

Answer (score 2):

addition of below in wblogic-application worked out

```
<package-name>org.hibernate.*</package-name>
<package-name>javax.validation.*</package-name>
<package-name>javax.validation.spi.*</package-name>
```

if using Hibernate 5.x and above, add the above in weblogic-application.xml

Thanks,

Comment: Does this work for WebSphere? Any chance anyone knows the configuration file name and location to put these in for WS?