# Error creating bean with name 'defaultValidator' defined in class path resource

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jboss

I am getting the following Error while trying to deploy my spring boot application on JBOSS. It works well on embedded Tomcat Server though. I tried to browse through Stack overflow to find similar issues. Could not find a solution yet. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
00:36:34,356 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) Application run failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultValidator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.Configuration.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$123/1614986064.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) [spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) [spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.JBossContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(JBossContextConfig.java:187) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:115) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3775) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:163) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.Configuration.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.configureParameterNameProvider(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:314) [spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:290) [spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 30 more
```

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError` almost always means mismatched dependency versions.

Comment: probably you have problem with dependencies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34721932/how-to-solve-nosuchmethoderror-for-javax-validation-when-deploying-a-spring-boot

Comment: U found any solution for this issue?

Comment: Look for validation api implementation (jar) in your JBoss.

Answer (score 8):

I resolved it in springboot2.0 by adding org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation in the build.gradle
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation

Answer (score 2):

The error is thrown from the org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ package if the spring boot is unable to auto configure the bean.The possible reasons for this error includes dependencies mismatch, broken dependencies or missing dependencies.Here is the solution

> 1. Update maven project by right clicking on your project,scroll down to maven and in side bar and choose update maven project. Mark force update of snapshots/releases checkbox and click ok (Eclipse / STS IDE). This will update the dependencies and build the project fixing dependencies related problem.

[image]

> 2. If the error is not resolved you can also try updating your bean validation api manually by adding the dependency to your pom file.
>      https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api/2.0.1.Final

Answer (score 1):

I was also fetching the same issue when i tried to run my spring boot application. After a lot of search i got my problem is that it might be missing Spring JPA, Hibernate, Mysql or maybe jackson in my pom.xml file. so i just added this dependency and it works fine.

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>        
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>            
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId> 
 </dependency>
```

it might help, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error when trying to use spring boot in a Java 9 modularized application. In the end I had to require `com.fasterxml.classmate`. I managed to start a rest api with an echo controller with the following pom dependecies and module-info:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

```
module mymodule {
    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
    requires spring.core;
    requires spring.web;
    requires com.fasterxml.classmate;

    exports mymodule;

    opens mymodule;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I update the [Bean Validation API] dependency to the latest one. It fixed my problem.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Reference Link: 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception as below. I was using Tomcat 7 to deploy a spring boot web app.  I changed it to tomcat 8 and it resolved. 
but its obvious that changing the server is not a easy and feasible solution in most of the case. 
adding the missing dependency for java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELManager would resolve it.

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultValidator' defined in class path resource [org/sprin          gframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframe          work.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean]: Factory method 'defaul          tValidator' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELManager
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656)