# Error creating Bean with name 'defaultValidator'

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation

I have an entity class InAppNotification.java that looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "notification")
public class InAppNotification {
    
    @Column(name = "inapptext")
    String text;
    
    @Column(name = "deeplink")
    String deepLink;
    
    @Column(name = "userid")
    Integer userId;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "isread")
    Boolean isRead = false;
```

Am using JPA to handle the database queries and this is how the jpa interface is defined:

```
public interface InAppNotificationRepository extends JpaRepository<InAppNotification, Long> {

    List<InAppNotification> findByUserId(@Param("userid") Integer userId);
    
}
```

This is how my application.properties looks like:

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://....
spring.datasource.username= ....
spring.datasource.password= ....

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation= true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect


# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
```

However, when I try to package the application after building by running `mvn clean package`
This is the issue that I am getting:

[image]

[An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location: javax.el.ELManager.getExpressionFactory(ELManager.java:38)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjgUx.png)

[[EDIT]] This is how my pom.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.demoproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>chart</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>chat</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
        <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.social/spring-social-linkedin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-linkedin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
    <version>4.4</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.11</version>
</dependency>



    
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20080701</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.json/javax.json-api -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.4</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/javax.mail -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4</version>
</dependency>




<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.2.12</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.773</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.maxmind.geoip2</groupId>
    <artifactId>geoip2</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>biz.paluch.redis</groupId>
    <artifactId>lettuce</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.reflections</groupId> <artifactId>reflections</artifactId> <version>0.9.9-RC1</version> </dependency> -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>        
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>            
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency> -->


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.12.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId> 
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Tried with mvn clean install, and the suggestions listed over here - [Error creating bean with name 'defaultValidator' defined in class path resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51853200/error-creating-bean-with-name-defaultvalidator-defined-in-class-path-resource).

Didn't help.

Comment: Can you please share full pom.xml file

Comment: Shared ful pom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replicated this issue and fixed it by removing some unnecessary dependencies available in `pom.xml`

**Issue:**

Some unnecessary dependencies are available in `pom.xml` that is causing this issue.

**Solution:**

Please remove the following dependencies from `pom.xml` and try again.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>        
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>            
</dependency>
```

**Why?:**

If you are using SpringBoot framework then following dependencies are enough to do database connectivity

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId> 
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.2.12</version>
</dependency>
```

and this dependency is enough to do Hibernate-related validations like annotations`@NotEmpty`, `@Pattern`, `@Min`, `@Max` etc

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```